# Pass flags to Python Script from Node/Express app python-shell

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express

I am trying to figure out how to pass flags to a python script from a Node/Express application. When in the command line I execute the script by running:

```
python ndbc.py --buoy 46232
```

I am using the python-shell module, which I think should allow me to do this, but I am not entirely sure how it works.

python-shell documentation:

https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell#running-a-python-script-with-arguments-and-options

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from the README, something like this should work:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var options = {
  args: ['--buoy', '46232']
};

PythonShell.run('ndbc.py', options, function (err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('results: %j', results);
});
```

Comment: thank you! I will give this a shot just to understand the pythonShell module a bit better. With the help of one of my friends that is working on the project with me, we actually came up with another  solution that works. I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution that used the child_process Module:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var pyArgs = {
  // make arguments that take no parameters (ie, --json) true or false
  "buoy": '46232',
  "datasource": 'http',
  "json": true,
  "datatype": "spectra",
  "units": 'ft'
};
//example
pyArgs.datatype = '9band';

function flagGen(args) {
  var flags = '';
  for (var a in args) {
    if (args.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
      if (typeof(pyArgs[a]) == 'string'){
        flags += " --" + a + ' ' + pyArgs[a];
      }
      else {
        if (pyArgs[a] == true)
          flags += ' --' + a;
      }
    }
  }
  return flags;
}

var pyPath = './';
var buoyData = ''
var execstr = 'python ' + path.join(pyPath, 'ndbc.py') + flagGen(pyArgs);
var child = exec(execstr, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(stderr)
  }
  else {
    buoyData= JSON.parse(stdout);
    console.log(buoyData);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested:

```js
const PyShell = require("python-shell");

let options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonPath: 'your_python_path',
    pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
    args: ['-p {"a":1, "b":"123"}']
};

let pyshell = new PyShell.PythonShell('your_script_path', options);

pyshell.on('message', function(message) {
    // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
    console.log("Received", message);
});

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit
pyshell.end(function(err, code, signal) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The exit code was: ' + code);
    console.log('The exit signal was: ' + signal);
    console.log('finished');
});
```